# Making a phone call in the background

Tags: android, android-activity

I want my background Service to make a call, so I use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:77777777"));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
startActivity(intent);
```

If the user is already on the phone call, then his call is being paused.

I do not want to disturb his call.
Is it possible for my service to make a quiet phone call? meaning: to make call and somehow leaving the current phone call undisturbed?

Comment: How.... would you expect that to work?

Comment: no need to talk. I just the call to be made

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible for my service to make a quiet phone call?

No.

Comment: And let me add: **Luckily**. How insecure would a system be, that allows every virus maker to drain my wallet through undesired phone calls?